# Microsoft Graph - Get MemberOf

Tags: c#, xamarin, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access the groups a user is a member of using the Microsoft Graph API.
I'm facing an issue because I think my permissions are set correctly, however, when I sign into the app, I get the message :

> ```
> AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.
> ```

The weird thing is that I'm only asking for this permission scope :

public static String[] ClientScope = { "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All", "Group.Read.All"};

What makes me confused is that if I sign in the Microsoft Graph explorer and go to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf , 
I get the correct results.
I got an admin to consent to the permissions I'm asking in the scope of course.

Has anyone encountered that issue ?

Any idea how I should correct that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [memberOf](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof) API requires one of the following scopes:

- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Regardless of which of these scopes you choose, they all will require administrative consent before a regular user can authorize them. To do this,  you'll first need to have them go through the “Admin Consent” workflow. This workflow requires an administrator but once complete any users of your application will have “admin consent” to the restricted scope.

For example, you would normally you would then authenticate users by redirecting them to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?<your params>`.

Since this scope requires an Admin however,  you fist need to obtain consent by first having an Admin authenticate by redirecting them to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?<yours params>`.

Once an Admin grants consent, normal users will be able to use OAUTH to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
You must have missed this : " I got an admin to consent to the permissions I'm asking in the scope of course."
I have been able to access the groups with the Group.Read.All scope.

Comment: I understand, but you need one of those additional scopes in order to use `memberOf`. The `Group.Read.All` scope won't work for this method. Graph Explorer includes those scopes which is why it is working there.

Comment: How is it possible that I am able to fetch the groups from my code then ?
If I shouldn't be able, the groups would be set to null, right ?

Comment: Groups applies to Outlook Groups. The `memberOf` method however is scoped higher (e.g. it includes security groups) and therefore requires a higher level of access.

Comment: Oh okay I get it now.
Thanks a lot for the time you spent with me !